# Save customizer default values to DB on theme activation

Tags: wpdb, theme-customizer

i am working with multisite.

each time i activate some theme in new blog, i need to go to customizer and click the "save" to save all the values to db so i could use the with `get_theme_mod`

if there is a way to save me time by  save customizer default values to db on theme activation?

Comment: no one knows how to save default values to DB.

Comment: don't save default values to the db, use the second argument of `get_theme_mod` to pass a default value in the case that the theme mod doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi @Milo Thanks for the suggestion. i did not think on this. can you give me example hoe to get default value true get_theme_mod

Comment: simple use http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248570/wordpress-customizer-not-setting-default-value-upon-initial-install/248605#248605 @need-help